# how to use a variable from one class in another class without passing the class as an argument in the constructor

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to use `self.numbers` and `self.suits` from the `Cards` class in the `Deck` class. The only way i know to do this is what is shown below. Pass `class.card` as an argument in the class `Deck`'s `__init__` method. Here is the problem. In order to then use the `Deck` class, I have to pass an argument as well and i do not need or want to do that. Hopefully, I'm explaining myself well. I have the same problem trying to pass variables from the `Card` class and the `Deck` class in the `Player` class.

Here is the code:

```
import random


class Card:

    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']
        self.suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades']

    # print the current card
    def __str__(self):
        print(f'{self.numbers} of {self.suits}')


class Deck(Card):
    def __init__(self, class_card):
        super().__init__()
        self.deck = []
        self.numbers = class_card.numbers
        self.suits = class_card.suits

    # create a new deck of cards
    def create_deck(self):
        for suit in self.suits:
            for number in self.numbers:
                self.deck.append([number, suit])
                return self.deck

    # shuffle the deck of cards before the start of the game
    def shuffle_deck(self, deck):
        random.shuffle(deck)

class Player(Deck):
    def __init__(self, class_deck):
        super().__init__()
        self.hand = []
        self.count_cards = 0
        self.score = 0

    # draw a card from the deck
    def draw_card(self):
        drawn_card = self.hand.append(self.deck[-1])
        return drawn_card

    # count the cards in the players hand
    def count_hand(self):
        self.count_cards = len(self.deck)
        return self.count_cards

    # calculate the score each time the player wins
    def calculate_score(self):
        pass
```

Comment: I should add that I just started with OOP and this is a card game for War.  It is my first project to practice OOP in Python.

Comment: Your `Card` class doesn't make a lot of sense.  An instance of `Card` should represent a single card, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.  Inheritence should satisfy an "is a" relationship.  So if `Deck` is a subclass of `Card`, that means that every `Deck` is a `Card`.  Since that's not true, you should reconsider having your `Deck` class inherit from `Card` (the same with `Player` and `Deck`).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `super().__init__()` the deck will inherit the numbers and suits attribute from card. See the follows:

```
import random


class Card:

    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']
        self.suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades']

    # print the current card
    def __str__(self):
        print(f'{self.numbers} of {self.suits}')


class Deck(Card):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.deck = []

    # create a new deck of cards
    def create_deck(self):
        for suit in self.suits:
            for number in self.numbers:
                self.deck.append([number, suit])
        return self

    # shuffle the deck of cards before the start of the game
    def shuffle_deck(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.deck)

    def pop(self):
        return self.deck.pop()


class People:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Player(People):
    def __init__(self, name, deck):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.hand = []
        self.count_cards = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.deck = deck

    # draw a card from the deck
    def draw_card(self):
        drawn_card = self.hand.append(self.deck.pop())
        return drawn_card

    # count the cards in the players hand
    def count_hand(self):
        self.count_cards = len(self.hand)
        return self.count_cards

    # calculate the score each time the player wins
    def calculate_score(self):
        pass


def main():
    deck = Deck().create_deck()
    players = [Player(name, deck) for name in ('Jim', 'Ben', 'Paul', 'Wang')]
    deck.shuffle_deck()
    i = 0
    while len(deck):
        players[i].draw_card()
        i = (i + 1) % len(players)
    for p in players:
        print(p.name, p.count_hand(), p.calculate_score())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Jim 14 None
Ben 14 None
Paul 14 None
Wang 14 None
```

However, my recommend solution is like this:

```
import random


class Card:
    numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']
    suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades']

    def __init__(self, number, suit):
        self.number = number
        self.suit = suit
        self.score = self.numbers.index(number) * 10 + self.suits.index(suit)

    # print the current card
    def __str__(self):
        print(f'{self.number} of {self.suit}')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.score == other.score

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.score < other.score


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = [
            Card(num, suit) for num in Card.numbers for suit in Card.suits
        ]

    # shuffle the deck of cards before the start of the game
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)
        return self

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.deck)

    def pop(self):
        return self.deck.pop()


class People:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Player(People):
    def __init__(self, name, deck):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.hand = []
        self.count_cards = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.deck = deck

    # draw a card from the deck
    def draw_card(self):
        drawn_card = self.hand.append(self.deck.pop())
        return drawn_card

    # count the cards in the players hand
    def count_hand(self):
        self.count_cards = len(self.hand)
        return self.count_cards

    # calculate the score each time the player wins
    def calculate_score(self):
        return sum(card.score for card in self.hand)


def main():
    deck = Deck().shuffle()
    players = [Player(name, deck) for name in ('Jim', 'Ben', 'Paul', 'Wang')]
    i = 0
    while len(deck):
        players[i].draw_card()
        i = (i + 1) % len(players)
    for p in players:
        print(p.name, p.count_hand(), p.calculate_score())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```